# Operator overloading placement and redundancy

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading

I have multiple structs as follows: Vector2, Vector3, Vector4. Each struct has operator overloads defined for basic arithmetic operations as well as implicit and explicit casting.

So far, I have added all possible combinations in the Vector4 class:

```
public static Vector4 operator + (Vector4 v1, Vector4 v2) { return (new Vector4(...)); }
public static Vector4 operator + (Vector4 v1, Vector3 v2) { return (new Vector4(...)); }
public static Vector4 operator + (Vector3 v1, Vector4 v2) { return (new Vector4(...)); }

public static implicit operator Vector4 (Vector2 v) { return (new Vector4(v)); }
public static implicit operator Vector4 (Vector3 v) { return (new Vector4(v)); }

public static explicit operator Vector3 (Vector4 v) { return (new Vector3(v)); }
public static explicit operator Vector2 (Vector4 v) { return (new Vector2(v)); }
```

Is there a guideline as to which operators are a better fit in which struct? I can't imagine hurting performance either way but am interested in knowing what would be more intuitive for other developers if they came across this code. The number of operator combinations quickly goes into the dozens.

By the way, duplicating these operators in other classes is not causing a compile time error. I have not checked which implementation would be called but that's besides the point.

Comment: What is the difference between these structs?  Are they 2, 3 and 4-dimensional vectors?

Comment: @dbc: Yes. Vector2 (x, y). Vector3 (x, y, z). Vector4 (x, y, z, w). So going down dimensions should require explicit casting but going up dimensions should be implicit.

Comment: So.. if you add two Vector2 structs, I imagine you do not want a Vector4 return type or else you'll have to cast. It seems to me you'd want to implement the operator for addition to itself for each

Comment: @Alan: That's correct. Each vector type will get it's own operators. My question is about those operators where two different kinds of structs are being processed. Which return type with which parameters should go in which class.

Comment: For example, look at the third + operator. Is that a better fit for the Vector3 class? Hope I'm explaining this all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each class represents two, three and four-dimensional vectors, I think it should be possible for you to reduce your code somewhat.  That's because the definitions of vector arithmetic *between vectors of differing dimension* are redundant as long as you have the necessary implicit up-conversions.  Thus operators like the following will not be needed:

```
public static Vector4 operator + (Vector4 v1, Vector3 v2) { return (new Vector4(...)); }
public static Vector4 operator + (Vector3 v1, Vector4 v2) { return (new Vector4(...)); }
```

I'd also suggest making the lower-dimension vectors handle up-conversions to, and down-conversions from, higher dimension vectors.  That's because down-conversion strips information, and the choice of how to do it should be in the "more limited" struct.

Thus, `VectorI` structs would need implicit up-conversions to all `VectorI+J` and explicit down-conversions to all `VectorI-J` structs.  In addition, the VectorI structs would need to implement their own vector arithmetic.  But since 'I' only has values 2, 3 and 4, that means:

1. Vector2 needs implicit conversions to Vector3 and Vector4, as well as explicit down-conversions from Vector3 and Vector4.
2. Vector3 needs implicit conversions to Vector4 as well as explicit down-conversions from Vector4.
3. Vector4 needs no conversions.
4. All 4 structs implement linear algebra methods for themselves, between vectors of the same dimension only.

I just tested this scheme and adding disparate Vector2, Vector3 and Vector4 structs works as expected with the implicit conversion being done.

**Update**

Just made a quick prototype implementation for addition, and all the cross-dimension additions work as expected:

```
public struct Vector2
{
    public double x, y;

    public Vector2(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x; this.y = y;
    }

    #region linear algebra

    public static Vector2 operator +(Vector2 first, Vector2 second)
    {
        return new Vector2(first.x + second.x, first.y + second.y);
    }

    #endregion

    #region conversions to/from higher dimensions

    public static implicit operator Vector3(Vector2 v2)
    {
        return new Vector3(v2.x, v2.y, 0);
    }

    public static implicit operator Vector4(Vector2 v2)
    {
        return new Vector4(v2.x, v2.y, 0, 0);
    }

    public static explicit operator Vector2(Vector3 v3)
    {
        return new Vector2(v3.x, v3.y);
    }

    public static explicit operator Vector2(Vector4 v4)
    {
        return new Vector2(v4.x, v4.y);
    }

    #endregion
}

public struct Vector3
{
    public double x, y, z;

    public Vector3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z;
    }

    #region linear algebra

    public static Vector3 operator +(Vector3 first, Vector3 second)
    {
        return new Vector3(first.x + second.x, first.y + second.y, first.z + second.z);
    }

    #endregion

    #region conversions to/from higher dimensions

    public static implicit operator Vector4(Vector3 v3)
    {
        return new Vector4(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, 0);
    }

    public static explicit operator Vector3(Vector4 v4)
    {
        return new Vector3(v4.x, v4.y, v4.z);
    }

    #endregion
}

public struct Vector4
{
    public double x, y, z, w;

    public Vector4(double x, double y, double z, double w)
    {
        this.x = x; this.y = y; this.z = z; this.w = w;
    }

    #region linear algebra

    public static Vector4 operator +(Vector4 first, Vector4 second)
    {
        return new Vector4(first.x + second.x, first.y + second.y, first.z + second.z, first.w + second.w);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The following test code then works OK:

```
public static class VectorHelper
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var v2 = new Vector2(5, 5);
        var v3 = new Vector3(7, 7, 7);
        var v4 = new Vector4(3, 3, 3, 3);

        var res1 = v2 + v3;
        Debug.Assert(res1.GetType().Name == "Vector3"); // No assert
        var res2 = v3 + v4;
        Debug.Assert(res2.GetType().Name == "Vector4"); // No assert
        var res3 = v2 + v4;
        Debug.Assert(res3.GetType().Name == "Vector4"); // No assert
        Debug.Assert(res3.x == 8 && res3.y == 8 && res3.z == 3 && res3.w == 3); // No assert
    }
}
```